# CSS image resize and blank bottom area

Tags: css, image

So, in my previous post I was asking how I can diplay a `500x500 image`, with that `image` to only be resized towards the `x axis` and not `y`.

```
.image { 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-image: url('http://www.seedsavers.org/site/img/SEO%20Images/0841-benarys-giant-zinnia-flower.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I use `border` to understand a bit better the borders of the image. I tested this and works fine except for the fact that when I resize it towards the `x axis` it's indeed resized but it gives a blank area at the bottom:

[image]

How can I fix this so no blank bottom area appears, the border to fit always the image? Ty

Comment: Decrease height to image height?

Comment: I recommend using `<img>` tags if you want to keep things clean. https://jsfiddle.net/urLxfsu4/

Answer (score 0):

The width of your container is not 500px, so therefore the background image is being reduced in height to maintain its aspect ratio. If you would like to entirely fill the `<div>`, you can use `background-size: cover`, as follows:

```css
.image { 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-image: url('http://www.seedsavers.org/site/img/SEO%20Images/0841-benarys-giant-zinnia-flower.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: But then the image is displayed not completely

Comment: Yes, but you cannot have it both ways. You either resize proportionally and have the whitespace, or cover and don't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use img tag and make this img responsive? here is my solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/7rwp5jf4/
 Html:

```
<div>
 <img src="http://www.seedsavers.org/site/img/SEO%20Images/0841-benarys-giant-zinnia-flower.jpg">
</div>
```

Css:

```
DIV { 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
div img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```